# Be welcoming - case in point

Tags: discussion

Regarding the recent discussion on 'be welcoming', here's an example:

[Where can one find safety regulations for storing, handling, and using rocket fuels](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27026/where-can-one-find-safety-regulations-for-storing-handling-and-using-rocket-fu) - this question got put on hold for being too broad.

While I can see that point, I can also see that this user isn't expecting a complete and rigorous answer. He just needs a starting point, which fits neatly in a 3-paragraph SE answer. It's also an answer that can't be easily arrived at by Googling.

IMO this is what the 'be welcoming' discussion is about: closing questions by new users instead of helping them on their way. Or am I reading this situation incorrectly?

Comment: Actually, I agree with you, which is why I stepped in with the comment to explain to the user what was going on with the close votes. The user has no idea why resource requests are immediately viewed negatively around here. That said, I do see how the question "How how do companies like SpaceX or Blue Origin know how to handle hazardous and flammable fuels?" could be interpreted in a really broad way. I think we need to make a better attempt to refine the question to be clearly on topic.

Comment: I don't want to appear to be needlessly intervening as a mod, but Hobbes, if you edited the question to frame it in terms of what you perceive the user to be looking for, I would reopen.

Comment: You can also leave a comment on the question explaining to the OP what motivated the change and explaining that if you misrepresented what they are looking for that they are free to edit further.

Comment: Is the issue that it's a list answer that could change? The recent comment by gwally seems to cover a large chunk of the answer in the length of a comment.

Comment: I'd say my main issue with the closing would be that none of the people who voted to close left a comment explaining why. I'd say that normally, if you don't have time to do the editing or commenting that goes with closing, leave it until a time that you do.

Comment: @kimholder when I voted to close (`2018-05-02 01:00:14Z`), (also https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMriQ.png) *there was already* a helpful [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27026/safety-regulations-for-storing-handling-and-using-rocket-fuels#comment80169_27026) (posted `2018-05-01 16:00:54Z`). Since I agreed with the comment, I don't feel there was a need for a "me too" comment. So while I agree that silent close-voting is a problem (see my [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27058/#comment80286_27058)), I don't think you are characterizing this situation correctly.

Comment: @uhoh to me called2voyage's comment doesn't help me understand the closure. It's a dense topic - okay, but it only asked for some references. Since i don't understand it, it's easy for me to see how the asker may well not understand it. Called2voyage's first comment above expands on this in the sense that he picked up that it's an issue of it being a resource request. So, the issue is it's a list answer that could change? I genuinely don't understand the initial closure, so i see a need there for a further comment by someone who voted for that.

Answer (score 2):

I've reopened and removed some of the comments. Thanks for being proactive!